# How to get (sub)class name from a static method in Python?

Tags: python, reflection, function-call, static-methods

If I define:

```
class Bar(object):

    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        # code
        pass

class Foo(Bar):
    # code
    pass
```

Is it possible for a function call Foo.bar() to determine the class name Foo?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Replace the staticmethod with a classmethod.  This will be passed the class when it is called, so you can get the class name from that.

```
class Bar(object):

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        # code
        print cls.__name__

class Foo(Bar):
    # code
    pass

>>> Bar.bar()
Bar

>>> Foo.bar()
Foo
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question was how to do it with a static method.

Comment: What happens when this is not possible -- for example, a third party library relies on a specific signature?

Comment: `classmethods` are "static" methods, they have no access to an object which would require the `self` parameter, `cls` only has access to the Class and not an Object Instance. The difference is that a `classmethod` can modify the state of the Class itself @sebix

Answer (score 3):

If you need to find the class information, the appropriate way is to use `@classmethod`.

```
class Bar(object):
    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        # code
        print(cls.__name__)

class Foo(Bar):
    # code
    pass
```

Now your `bar` method has a reference to the class as `cls` which is the actual class of the caller. And as shown in the code, `cls.__name__` is the **name** of the class you are looking for.

```
>>> Foo.bar()
Foo
>>> Bar.bar()
Bar
```

Answer (score 2):

As option, if you need determine class from staticmethod (not classmethod) I guess following code could be helpful:

```
class Bar(object):
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        pass


class Foo(Bar):
    pass


foo_instance = Foo()
bar_static_function = foo_instance.bar
class_name = bar_static_function.__qualname__.split(".")[0]
print(class_name)  # Foo
```