# In python how to get name of a class inside its static method

Tags: python

how to get name of a class inside static method, i have inheritance
and want name of derived class

IN following example what shall be there in place of **XXX** in method  my_name()

```
class snake()
   @staticmethod
   def my_name():  
      print XXX.__name___

class python (snake)
   pass
class cobra (snake)
   pass

python.my_name()
# I want output to be python

cobra.my_name()   
# I want output to be cobra
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get (sub)class name from a static method in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596641/how-to-get-subclass-name-from-a-static-method-in-python)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is impossible for a static method.  Use a class method instead:

```
class Snake(object):
    @classmethod
    def my_name(cls):  
        print cls.__name__
```

Comment: As Lennart said, it's not "impossible", but it's a very bad idea. Pretend I never said the following, but ... you could do it using the `inspect` module with `inspect.currentframe()`, and then loading and searching through the source file to find the name of the function and then its class. :-)

Answer (score 12):

A static method in Python is for all intents and purposes just a function. It knows nothing about the class, so you should not do it. It's probably possible, most things tend do be. But it's Wrong. :)

And in this case, you clearly *do* care about the class, so you don't want a static method.
So use a class method.