# How do I find the class of my static method inside of it?

Tags: django, class, static

Given I am inside a @staticmethod, how can I find the name of the current class ?

As i don't have access to `self.__class__.__name__`

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596641/how-to-get-subclass-name-from-a-static-method-in-python.

Comment: yes. add it as an answer and I close it up. Once I have that name, what can I do to call some class managet   'str'.objects won't work obviously.

Comment: I would award you the answer as you answered first. For that you'd need to add a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in this answer [How to get (sub)class name from a static method in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596641/how-to-get-subclass-name-from-a-static-method-in-python)

you can change the `@staticmethod` to a `@classmethod` which takes the class as a parameter:

```
class Bar(object):

    @classmethod
    def bar(cls):
        print cls.__name__
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the method (e.g. it's one you wrote), the best way is to use the `@classmethod` decorator instead. That will send the class as the first argument:

```
class Spam(object):
    @classmethod
    def eggs(cls):
        return cls.__name__
```